# How can I add various sections in Shopify on register page? For example, phone number?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-template

How can I add phone number section in Shopify on register page? I want to populate phone numbers of our customers in order to SMS marketing? We are selling pet products, if i could know whether our customers have a cat or a dog, that would be great. I want my customer data to be segmented based on these variables.

```
 </div>
    <div class="field">
      <input
        type="email"
        name="customer[email]"
        id="RegisterForm-email"
        {% if form.email %}
          value="{{ form.email }}"
        {% endif %}
        spellcheck="false"
        autocapitalize="off"
        autocomplete="email"
        aria-required="true"
        {% if form.errors contains 'email' %}
          aria-invalid="true"
          aria-describedby="RegisterForm-email-error"
        {% endif %}
        placeholder="{{ 'customer.register.email' | t }}"
      >
      <label for="RegisterForm-email">
        {{ 'customer.register.email' | t }}
      </label>
    </div>
```

I tried replacing "email" with "phone", however it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use phone at register https://shopify.dev/themes/architecture/templates/customers-register, but here are a few solutions:

- You can add phone as a field for customer/address and on successful customer register just make another request to save number inside default address. (https://shopify.dev/themes/architecture/templates/customers-addresses)
- You can add phone field and save it as a metafield for customer after successful register request. (https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/metafield)

Answer (score 0):

To create a contact page:

From your Shopify admin, go to Online Store > Pages.
Click Add page.
In the Title box, type a title for your contact page, such as Contact us or Get in touch.
In the Content box, type any text that you want to appear above the contact form. You can leave this section blank.

Some information that you might want to add in the Content box:

Short, friendly text such as "We'll get back to you as soon as we can"
Your store's address, with an image of your physical storefront, if you have a retail location
Your phone number, if you want customers to be able to reach you by phone
In the Online store section, choose contact from the Theme template drop-down menu.

Click Save.

Your contact form should now be visible on your Contact page.

You might need to add your contact page to your navigation menu to make it visible on your store.

If your theme supports adding a contact form as a section, then you can add a contact form to existing pages. Refer to Sections and Blocks for more information.
#copied from shopify help center...